# Can't get jvectormap's setFocus method to work with region name

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I am trying to focus on a specific region on the map using region name instead of latitudes and longitudes.

for example, this doesn't work for me:

```
map.setFocus({region: 'IN'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of researching, I got this to work by doing this:

```
    var mapObj = $('#world-map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

    mapObj.setFocus({region: 'IN'})
```